# Symfony Assetic Dump With Multiple filters

Tags: symfony, dump, assetic

Is it possible to use multiple assetic dump filters for css assets. I want to achieve "cssuglify" filter followed by "cssrewrite" filter. As of now I tried to figure it out so far only found that we can apply only one filter at a time, otherwise write your own asset management scripts. Any help or clue would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the filter attribute more than once inside {% stylesheets %}:

```
{% stylesheets filter='cssuglify' filter='cssrewrite'
  ......
  ......
%}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset_url }}" />
{% end stylesheets %}
```